# Topology Open Balls and Proving Open Sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $ x ∈ ℝ^n $ and $ ε > 0 $. Prove that the open ball $ B_ε(x) $ is an open set (rigorously!).

I am having trouble with the problem above. If I am understanding it correctly I should be able to set $ x ∈ ℝ^n $ and $ ε > 0 $. Then the open ball $ B_ε(x) $ centered at $ x $ of radius $ ε $ is the set {$ x ∈ ℝ^n | d(x,x_o) < ε $}. If I am correct thus far then a subset $ u\subseteqℝ^n $ is open if $ \forall$ $ x \in u$, $ \exists$ $ ε>0 $ such that $ B_ε (x)\subseteq u $.

This is as far as I can get. I do not know if this is all I have to do or if I need to do something else? If someone could Help out I would really appreciate it!

Comment: General idea: given a point in the open ball, $p \in B_\epsilon(x)$, can you find $\delta$ such that $B_\delta(p) \subset B_\epsilon(x)$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Let $y\in B_\epsilon(x)$. Then $d(y,x)=r<\epsilon$. Now take any $t\in (0,\epsilon-r)$. Can you show that $B_t(y)\subseteq B_\epsilon(x)$?

Comment: would it be $ d(y,x) $ $ \le $  $ d(y,x_o) + d(x_o,x) $ $ \lt $ $ t + d(x_0,x) = \epsilon $ which would show that $ y \in B_\epsilon (x) $ which would also show that $ B_t (y) \subseteq B_\epsilon (x) $ ?

Comment: To the proposer: Yes. Exactly right.

Comment: No, $d(y,x)<\epsilon$ is something you already know. You need to show that any element in $B_t(y)$ is in $B_\epsilon(x)$. So let $z\in B_t(y)$. Then $d(z,x)\leq d(z,y)+d(y,x)<t+r<(\epsilon-r)+r=\epsilon$. Hence $z \in B_\epsilon(x)$.

Comment: Oh, okay that makes sense! Thank you for your help!